# Extend to display decimal point number for more numbers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display some decimal points.

Here are some examples.

```
console.log(1/100); // 0.01;
console.log(1/1000000); // 0.000001;
console.log(1/10000000); // le-7; but I want to see 0.0000001;
console.log(1/100000000); // le-8; but I want to see 0.00000001;
```

How to show decimal point numbers with keeping format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.toFixed(n)`:

```js
console.log((1/10000000).toFixed(10))
```

Comment: OMG, I've known `toFixed()` but I can't think about it...